# How may i use three.js to create a fatline

Tags: three.js, line, drawing

Currently, I'm working on a three.js project where i must use a lot of points to drow a fat line ;I had use the lineWidth property of THREE.LineBasicMaterial,but it is not work;  My big question now is how to to do it?
this is the code

```
createLine_old() {
      const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff,
        linewidth: 10
      });

      const points = [];
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, 0, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0));
      const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);

      const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
      scene.add(line);
    }
```

At last, any help would be appreciated;

Comment: One option, is to use fat lines approach: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fat#webgl_lines_fat

Comment: Thanks prisoner849 very mush  ,I had  watch it  but It is hard to understand, so i;m finding the other options

Comment: Another option: https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine

Comment: Thanks again ,i think i can resolve i t